# Import Financial chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to implement the Financial 'candlestick' chart type from the Chartjs library (I'm using version 2.7.1).

I followed the steps of the example provided in the documentation, but I always get this error "chart.min.js: 10 Uncaught Error: 'candlestick' is not a chart type."

can anyone tell me how this type of extension is implemented?

Comment: I took a look into the Github of Chartjs i couldn't find candlestick? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.6.0/charts/line.html Even the latest version doesn't implement it directly. Maybe you'll need some additional library based on Chartjs.

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-chart-financial this is the type of graph I would like to implement

Comment: Have you tried to clone the example and get it to run. From this point onward you should be able to use it by modifying.

Comment: @sascha10000 he wont be able to use it in its current state even by cloning/modifying the example. Since he is using v2 of chart.js while the financial chart only works with v3 so he needs to update his chart.js version

Comment: yes, I've already tried but it always gives me the Uncaught Error

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 version of chart.js released and this version is for chart.js v3 since you are working with chart.js v2 you are not able to use this chart type so you will need to update to chart.js v3.

Chart.js v3 has some major breaking changes which you can read in the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

**Edit:**

While using the financial lib with bundlers you will need to import and register everything like so:

```js
import { OhlcElement, OhlcController, CandlestickElement, CandlestickController } from 'chartjs-chart-financial'
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto' // Easy way of importing everything

Chart.register(OhlcElement, OhlcController, CandlestickElement, CandlestickController)
```

Comment: tnks!!! this help me a lot!!!!

 but now the problem is change "Uncaught Error: "candlestick" is not a registered controller"

I think i'm going crazy

Comment: Thats because you need to import and register all the components, see updated answer