# Chartjs Financial Candlestick doesn't show graph Javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js, candlestick-chart

Goodmorning everyone,

I'm trying to implement the "candlestick" graph from the Chartjs library;

I took the example shown in the documentation as a guide and everything works correctly: the 'x' and 'y' axes show the correct values;
The problem is that the actual graph is not displayed, even if the Cartesian axes are present

this is the code used for implement Chart and the result image

```
var barCount = 5;
var initialDateStr = '01 Apr 2017 00:00 Z';

var barData = getRandomData(initialDateStr, barCount);
//console.log(barData)
//function lineData() { return barData.map(d => { return { x: d.x, y: d.c} }) };

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
            data: barData
        }]
    }
});

var getRandomInt = function(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
};

function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function randomBar(date, lastClose) {
    
    var open = +randomNumber(lastClose * 0.95, lastClose * 1.05).toFixed(2);
    var close = +randomNumber(open * 0.95, open * 1.05).toFixed(2);
    var high = +randomNumber(Math.max(open, close), Math.max(open, close) * 1.1).toFixed(2);
    var low = +randomNumber(Math.min(open, close) * 0.9, Math.min(open, close)).toFixed(2);
    return {
        x: date.valueOf(),
        o: open,
        h: high,
        l: low,
        c: close
    };

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Financial chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724115/import-financial-chartjs)

Comment: no, that was my first question.. today I chenged all my project, and this is the "new error"